# How can i include a comment section in my article view with validating?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, content-management-system

I have developed a simple CMS application with ASP.Net MVC 4, It includes an action method named "Article" that passes an "Article" model to the view:

```
// Article Model
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
}
// Action method
public ActionResult Article(int id=1)
{
        return View(GetArticleById(id));
}
```

In my "Article" view i want to include a commenting section. Now how can i get the new comment details according that i used "Article" as the model in my view? In my own way i created a form like the following code that manually gets the new comment details and posts them to an action named "New" in another control named "Comment", Am i going in the correct way? In this way i didn't succeed to validate new comment inputs.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("New","Comment",FormMethod.Post))
{
<input type="hidden" name="Id" value="@Model.Id" />
<div class="input-div">
    <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" name="Name" />
    <textarea placeholder="Your Comment" class="comment-textarea" id="Txt" name="Content"></textarea>
</div>
<div>
    <input class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Leave a comment" />
</div>
}
```

Sorry for bad English,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `CommentViewModel` representing your comment data and in `ArticleViewModel` have a `ICollection<CommentViewModel>` to display them.

The form that POST the new comment will be a form based on the field of the `CommentViewModel` and the action (New) will have a `CommentViewModel` as a parameter.

In this way the `ModelBinder` will do the job for you.

Keep in mind that your ViewModel must always represents data that you want to display and data that you want to pass to the controller so an important part in MVC is to create the right ViewModel based on your use case.

Your approact at the end is right but keep aware of the fact the name of fields in you model must have the same name of property in your model.

According to this you should add the validation attribute to property in your `Comment` class that based on your Form should be named as

```
Id
Name
Content
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks,Worked but how can I show the validation summary in the [Article] view from an external controller?(The [New] action in the [Comment] Controller)

Comment: you can do validation on data you post so if you post Comment you should add Validation attributes to the Comment class properties and then use @Html.ValidationSummary().

If your problem is to validate the comment in the action New (POST) and display the validation on the action that dispaly the article you can use TempData.

Take a look here maybe it can help http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx